# NHibernate and IoC IInterceptor

Tags: nhibernate, dependency-injection, ioc-container

I have been trying to implement a solution similar to what Ayende posts in his MSDN article, [Building a Desktop To-Do Application with NHibernate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819139.aspx). Fortunately, Skooletz wrote a similar article that follows up what I am trying to accomplish with his 3 part blog post on NHibernate interceptor magic tricks ([1](http://blog.scooletz.com/2011/02/03/nhibernate-interceptor-magic-tricks-pt-1/), [2](http://blog.scooletz.com/2011/02/04/nhibernate-interceptor-magic-tricks-pt-2/), [3](http://blog.scooletz.com/2011/02/14/nhibernate-interceptor-magic-tricks-pt-3/)). I am having trouble getting my POCO object's parametered constructor to be called by NHibernate when instantiating the object.

When I remove the protected parameterless constructor, NHibernate complains with an InvalidProxyTypeException: "The following types may not be used as proxies:
YourNamespace.YourClass: type should have a visible (public or protected) no-argument constructor". If I then add in the protected default constructor, NHibernate no longer complains, but the dependency (in the overloaded constructor) is never called causing the application to barf with a NullReferenceException at runtime when the dependency is not satisfied.

```
public MyClass
{
    IRequiredDependency dependency;

    public MyClass(IRequiredDependency dependency)
    {
        this.dependency = dependency;
    }

    protected MyClass() {}
}
```

I just can't seem to get NHibernate to call the overloaded constructor. Any thoughts?

Comment: What's "the dependency (in the overloaded constructor)"? Can you provide a little bit of code?

Comment: Did you call the parameterized constructor or did you initialize the dependency by an interceptor somehow?

Comment: Can you show the relevant interceptor code?

Comment: For related interceptor code, please refer to the Building a Desktop To-Do Application with NHibernate article referenced above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the configuration of the IoC container, you have to declare your type with the dependency in addition to the dependency itself.

```
        container.RegisterType<IRequiredDependency, RequiredDependency>();
        container.RegisterType<MyClass, MyClass>();
```

I missed that little tidbit from [Pablo's post](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/12/12/entities-behavior-injection.aspx) (where he registers the Invoice class in addition to its dependency, IInvoiceTotalCalculator) as I am using Unity instead of Windsor.

**One additional note:** I found is that if you would like to have any other overloaded constructors, make them internal, leave the default constructor as protected and have only a single public constructor that contains your dependencies. This tidbit helped tighten up some of my API design for the classes.